# Why is $\frac{e^{x}(x-1) }{ 1-x} = -e^{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

According to Wolfram Alpha $$\frac{e^{x}(x-1)}{ 1-x} = -e^{x}$$

I simply do not see how the algebra works out, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{x-1}{1-x}=-1$$

Do you see it now?

Answer (score 3):

Of course, for $x\neq 1$ this is true. We have
$$\frac{e^x(x-1)}{1-x}=\frac{e^x(x-1)}{-(x-1)}=-e^x\frac{x-1}{x-1}=-e^x$$
since $\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1$ for $x\neq 1$. For $x=1$ the expression in question is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Don't get distracted by the exponential function -- it's not really relevant.  The important thing to notice is that
$$\frac{x-1}{1-x}$$
is just a disguised version of $-1$.

If this doesn't seem obvious to you, try choosing a specific value of $x$ and evaluating the fraction.  Notice that the number in the numerator is always opposite in sign (but equal in magnitude) to the number in the denominator, so the ratio is $-1$.

(Note:  As several others have pointed out, this identity is only true if $x\ne 1$.  If $x = 1$ then the left-hand side is undefined.)

Answer (score 0):

I think WF  mistaked!

$\frac{e^{x}(x-1)}{ 1-x} = -e^{x}$ is wrong. Try $x=1$.